# How to use an extended class' name in an if statement

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods, arraylist

I am trying to use an extended class' name inside an if statement. For this class (the `giveAwayFish` class) it represents a person quitting and
returning all their items to the lake and/or giving them away to another fisher (this is only if the item is desirable to the fisher, otherwise it is thrown back into the lake). However if the person quitting catches `Treasure` (which is a class that has been extended), they keep it and do not return it to the lake or give it to another fisher. I tried writing the method but it is not working for some reason, if anyone can help me out on this it would be great. if anyone is wondering this is inside my `Fisher class`

```
public void giveAwayFish(Fisher fisher, Lake lake)
      {
        for(Catchable item : thingsCaught)
        {
          if(item.isDesirableTo(this) && !getClass().getSimpleName().equals("Treasure"))
          {
            fisher.keep(item);      
            this.numThingsCaught = 0;
             thingsCaught.clear(); //here thingsCaught represents an arraylist of items
                                   //of the person who is quitting
          }
          else if(getClass().getSimpleName().equals("Treasure"))
          {
             this.numThingsCaught = 1;
          }
          else
          {
             lake.add(item);
             this.numThingsCaught = 0;
              thingsCaught.clear();
          }
          sumOfWeight -= item.getWeight();
        }

      }
```

Comment: Maybe you could use `getClass() == Treasure.class` or `this instanceof Treasure`.

Comment: "It is not working"... we're not mind readers, could you share some more details?  Like the error message displayed by the compiler, the stack backtrace if it throws an exception, or what is the incorrect behavior and what you believe it should be.

Comment: well the error is basically when i run this, and say for example 'Suzy' is giving all her fish to 'fred' and suzy catches treasure in the beginning, even though this method is being used in the main program, she still gives fred the fish when the giveAway() method is used @ajb

Comment: Unrelated, but I question the design. It's should be relatively rare you need to query a type manually.

Comment: @user3330114 Sorry, but you're still assuming we know how this description is related to the code, and we don't.  At least I can't tell.  My suggestion: add `System.out.println(getClass().getSimpleName())` before your `if`. Maybe then you can see what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
else if(getClass().getSimpleName().equals("Treasure"))
```

why not just

```
else if(this instanceof Treasure)
```

or

```
else if(this.getClass().isAssignableFrom(Treasure.class));  //maybe the other way around?
```

?

The API for `Class.isAssignableFrom(cls)`:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)

Either `instanceof` or `isAssignableFrom` are much better starting points than analyzing the string's name.

Comment: Please note that these are **not** equivalent.  `instanceof` is `true` if the class is `Treasure` _or any subclass of Treasure;_ using equality on a class does not return `true` for subclasses.  However, I don't know which one is right because the OP has not provided info about the exact problem.

Comment: Right. They're not equivalent. `instanceof` or `isAssignableFrom(cls)` is a better starting point, however, than analyzing the classes string name. I think you made your comment before I added the `isAssignableFrom` part.

Comment: I clarified my answer.